# HTML tag replacement using regex and python

Tags: python, html, regex, tags

I have a Python script that will look at an HTML file that has the following format:

```
<DOC>
<HTML>
...
</HTML>
</DOC>
<DOC>
<HTML>
...
</HTML>
</DOC>
```

How do I remove all HTML tags (replace the tags with '') with the exception of the opening and closing DOC tags using regex in Python? Also, if I want to retain the alt-text of an  tag, what should the regex expression look like?

Comment: You should use a DOM parser, not a regular expression. See http://docs.python.org/library/xml.dom.html

Comment: And can you be more specific about what you want to remove?

Comment: I want to remove all tags except for the <DOC> and </DOC> tags.

Comment: Is 'html' a hypothetical element name and not really 'html'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

search and replace with this regex:  search for: <.*?> replace with: "

Answer (score 4):

For what you are trying to accomplish I would use BeautifulSoup rather than regex.

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Answer (score 2):

Check out [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), a really nice python library for dealing with xml. You can use drop_tag to accomplish what you are looking for.

```
from lxml import html 
h = html.fragment_fromstring('<doc>Hello <b>World!</b></doc>')
h.find('*').drop_tag()
print(html.tostring(h, encoding=unicode))

<doc>Hello World!</doc>
```